# Convert c#/selenium to python/selenium

Tags: c#, python, selenium

I'm converting a project over from c#/selenium to python/selenium.

We have a drop down within the site which has an id which is incremental, i.e:

```
Upl-employmentstatus-radio-01
Upl-employmentstatus-radio-02
......
```

So within the page model object we have added an element as follows:

```
public IWebElement EmploymentStatus(int option) => _driver.FindElement(By.Id($"upl-employmentstatus-radio-{option}")
```

the int option allows us to replace the value it selects depending on c#/selenium test.

So what is the equivalent is python for the page model element?

i've currently got the following:

```
self.Title = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 60).until(ec.visibility_of_element_located(webapp.driver.find_element_by_id("upl-title-radio-{option}")))
```

Answer (score 2):

The Python equivalent of C#'s string interpolation is f-string

```
f"upl-title-radio-{option}"
```

Answer (score 0):

In python use this code for a page object. Then you can pass in the variable and return the path.

```
 def self.Title(option):
     return WebDriverWait(self.driver,60).until(ec.visibility_of_element_located(webapp.driver.find_element_by_id(f"upl-title-radio-{option}")))
```